# InputStream to byte array causes OutOfMemory exception

Tags: .net, database, file

I am not able to write `InputStream` (containint file content) into database as `byte` array.

I had the following code, but with large files it sthrows `OutOfMemoryExceptoin`.

```
        var postedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];
        byte[] fileContent;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            postedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms); //error occures here
            fileContent = ms.ToArray();
        }
       // updating entity with new filecontent using INSERT statement
```

Can you suggest me how to convert InputStream properly to byte array, so I can write it into database? We need to support up to 100mb (edit: I have changed from 200 to 100) files.

P.S. I know that these are very big files, but for now this is the only way to handle them.

Comment: How are you uploading to the database? Ideally you'd find a way which didn't require everything in memory at a time...

Comment: Well, of course it does.  Storing 200 megabyte chunks in a database is also a rather bad idea.  OOM is otherwise simply avoided by letting your program run as a 64-bit process, remove the jitter forcing.

Comment: Read the file only file few lines at a time. Each time you read a few lines, save the relevant data to database, and then go back to reading next few lines from the file.

Comment: I am uploading using insertstatement. For now I cannot change this code, I just need to fix this issue with memory streamd and not the other things.

Comment: The only way to store files - is in databaes. We do not have other ways for now. So we are just storing what users upload and requirement is up to 200mb. The quetsion is not about that part, but about memory stream.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public byte[] FileToByteArray(string fileName)
{
    byte[] buff = null;
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, 
                                   FileMode.Open, 
                                   FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    long numBytes = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;
    buff = br.ReadBytes((int) numBytes);
    return buff;
}
```

Try this and let me know if it works for you......as per me it should work....